# How do I create custom roles using the Azure CLI?

Tags: azure-cli

I am trying to create a custom role in azure using the azure CLI.  I have been following this walk-through:

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/role-based-access-control-manage-access-azure-cli/

I have used the exact same example for the role definition (adjusting only for my subscriptionId).  When I run `azure role create` the output looks as though it is creating successfully:

```
info:    Executing command role create
info:    Validating role definition
+ Creating role definition "6b07875c-fa5b-4fc9-b95d-a665c3b4ad48"
info:    Created role definition 6b07875c-fa5b-4fc9-b95d-a665c3b4ad48
data:    Name             : Virtual Machine Operator
data:    Id               : 6b07875c-fa5b-4fc9-b95d-a665c3b4ad48
data:    Description      : Can monitor and restart virtual machines.
data:    AssignableScopes : 0=/subscriptions/xxxx
data:    Actions          : 0=Microsoft.Storage/*/read, 1=Microsoft.Network/*/read, 2=Microsoft.Compute/*/read, 3=Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/start/action, 4=Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/restart/action, 5=Microsoft.Authorization/*/read, 6=Microsoft.Resources/subscriptions/resourceGroups/read, 7=Microsoft.Insights/alertRules/*, 8=Microsoft.Insights/diagnosticSettings/*, 9=Microsoft.Support/*
data:    NotActions       :
data:    IsCustom         : true
data:
info:    role create command OK
```

However the new role does not show up when I run `azure role list` and `azure role show "Virtual Machine Operator"` return this:

```
info:    Executing command role show
+ Searching for role definitions
info:    No role definition matching the search criteria was found
info:    role show command OK
```

The only hint I can find that anything has happened is if I try and execute the `azure role create` again, which returns this:

```
info:    Executing command role create
info:    Validating role definition
+ Creating role definition "ce84ed80-ec75-4465-b668-b0752b959fcd"
error:   A role definition cannot be updated with a name that already exists.
error:   Error information has been recorded to C:\Users\James\.azure\azure.err
error:   role create command failed
```

Answer (score 0):

**This might be what you are looking for**

This is the Azure CLI Command to create a new role in Azure, where RoleInfo.json is the local file with all the configurations, scope, actions, data actions regarding that role.

You need to follow the Microsoft's Custom Role Creation Documentation to make sure everything is setup in a proper way.

```
az role definition create --role-definition RoleInfo.json
```

For example, the below code is a sample json for RateCardQueryRole

```
{
     “Name”: “MyRateCardRole”,
     “IsCustom”: true,
     “Description”: “Rate Card query role”,
     “Actions”: [
         “Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/vmSizes/read”,
         “Microsoft.Resources/subscriptions/locations/read”,
         “Microsoft.Resources/providers/read”,
         “Microsoft.ContainerService/containerServices/read”,
         “Microsoft.Commerce/RateCard/read”
     ],
     “AssignableScopes”: [
         “/subscriptions/YOUR_SUBSCRIPTION_ID”
     ]
}
```

Now, you can check for the newly created custom role using the below command in Azure CLI.

```
az role definition list --custom-role-only true --name "Role Name"
```

Replace Role Name with your new custom role name.

That's it. Voila! Hope this helps...